# How to use {N} application lifecycle events in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, nativescript

The documentation page for [Application Management](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-management) describes a bunch of application lifecycle events and how to use them in javascript. But I couldn't find out how to use them when I write my {N} application using Angular.

There is a documentation page for [Application Management](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/application-management.html) in Angular, but it is the same as for the NativeScript core.

How can I use those events in Angular?

Comment: The strange thing is I don't see how to pass in custom handlers to the nativeScriptBootstrap() which calls the application.start() method and registers the create event handler. The documentation must be wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/nativescript-angular/application.ts

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? For example, the `ngOnInit()` is useful, there are some neater hybrid tns and ng2 approaches that are nicer than the pure tns approach.

Comment: I'm trying to get the arguments, with which the application is started when launched from a push notification. It is described here: https://github.com/alg/nativescript-fcm/blob/master/readme.md

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the lifecycle events, but you need to add the handlers before the bootstrap because the code after the bootstrap will not be called in iOS.

For example, to listen to the application start event, you must add the listener in your main.ts:

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import { on as applicationOn, launchEvent, ApplicationEventData} from "application";

applicationOn(launchEvent, function (args: ApplicationEventData) {
    if (args.android) {
        // For Android applications, args.android is an android.content.Intent class.
        console.log("Launched Android application with the following intent: " + args.android + ".");
    } else if (args.ios !== undefined) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios is NSDictionary (launchOptions).
        console.log("Launched iOS application with options: " + args.ios);
    }
});

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: great answer! How would I go about to use a service on launchEvent though?